# Importing AMD module in to Mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, amd

I am using Mocha to test code exported as AMD module. Running mocha test gives me following error.

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/malintha/projects/...../xxx.js:1:63)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

The source which is tested as floows

```
define(['lodash', 'log', './yyy'], function(_, log, YYY) {

var xxxy = function() {

};

..............
});
```

And the mocha test

```
var expect    = require("chai").expect;
var sourceGenVisitor = require("../../xxx")

describe("", function() {
 describe("", function() {
  it("Checks generated source", function() {
     ...................
  });
  });
 });
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Ideally, the module under test should support both AMD and CommonJS. That way you don't have to wonder how to support AMD in Node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`amd-loader`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader). I used it for *years* in a project of mine that was structured as a collection of AMD modules. Install with:

```
`npm install amd-loader`
```

It then needs to be loaded before any AMD module. In general:

```
require("amd-loader");
```

For Mocha you can use the argument `--require amd-loader`. You can put it in your `test/mocha.opts` file if you don't want to have to remember typing it over and over.

Comment: Now I am getting 

"module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'". I have installed lodash and require it in my mocha test but still giving me error.

Comment: Your question here was tagged with `node.js` so I gave you an answer that works in Node. I see you wrote another question that uses a browser. If you are in a browser, then the simplest  method is to just use RequireJS as you show you are doing in that question.

Answer (score 1):

If you run mocha test with the typescript. Maybe you do this:

1. Install amd-loader:

   ```
   npm install amd-loader --save
   ```
2. Run mocha test:

   ```
   mocha  src/**/*test.ts --require ts-node/register -r amd-loader
   ```